# Swift retain cycle missing clarification

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, automatic-ref-counting

Apple has [documentation that describes how retain cycles work in closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html). This is their example of a closure that does not cause a retain cycle.

```swift
class HTMLElement {

    let name: String
    let text: String?

    lazy var asHTML: () -> String = {
        [unowned self] in
        if let text = self.text {
            return "<\(self.name)>\(text)</\(self.name)>"
        } else {
            return "<\(self.name) />"
        }
    }

    init(name: String, text: String? = nil) {
        self.name = name
        self.text = text
    }

    deinit {
        print("\(name) is being deinitialized")
    }

}
```

I occasionally like to pass a function definition into callback to try and rid my code of callback hell.

This example is a little contrived but does this cause a retain cycle? Would assigning a function like this to a closure ever cause a retain cycle?

```swift
class HTMLElement {

    let name: String
    let text: String?

    lazy var asHTML: () -> String = self.returnHTML

    init(name: String, text: String? = nil) {
        self.name = name
        self.text = text
    }

    func returnHTML() -> String {
        if let text = self.text {
            return "<\(self.name)>\(text)</\(self.name)>"
        } else {
            return "<\(self.name) />"
        }
    }

    deinit {
        print("\(name) is being deinitialized")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your example isn't contrived enough, actually. Let's make it simpler:

```
class C {
    lazy var f: () -> () = {
        [unowned self] in
        print(self)
    }
    init() {}
    func doF() {
        self.f()
    }
    deinit {
        print("C is being deinitialized")
    }
}
```

Now let's test it:

```
    let c = C()
    c.doF()
```

Result: When `c` goes out of scope, we see "C is being deinitialized".

Okay, but now delete `[unowned self] in`. Now when we test it, we *don't* see "C is being deinitialized". We have a retain cycle.

So yes, you have `self` retaining a function that refers to `self`, that's a retain cycle. You are right to break the cycle with `unowned self`.

(Of course, in my example, I'm taking account of the way your `lazy` complicates the picture. If we don't say `self.f()` — that is, if we never ask the `lazy var` to initialize itself — then of course it doesn't matter *what* the initializer for `f` is: it never gets initialized so there can be no retain cycle. But that is an extremely improbable scenario; if you were never going to initialize the `lazy var` then you wouldn't have the `lazy var` to begin with.)

Comment: Might want to see the discussion in my book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch05.html#SECweakSelf